# Set SSLParameters cipher order for a Server object [Java/Jetty]

Tags: ssl, jetty, encryption, java

JDK8 will have these two new methods in [SSLParameters](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters.html),

```
public final void setUseCipherSuitesOrder(boolean honorOrder);
public final boolean getUseCipherSuitesOrder();
```

which, as the name suggests honors the cipher suites order. I'm a bit confused about the usage though. I have a Jetty based server, the SSL configurations are done via XML (adds an SslContextFactory with the cipher suite include/exclude lists), and here is a code snippet for the server :

```
Server server = new Server();
Resource xml = Resource.newResource("/jetty-ssl-test.xml");
XmlConfiguration cfg = new XmlConfiguration(xml.getInputStream());
cfg.configure(server);
```

I searched a bit, and found [this nice test case from openjdk](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~xuelei/7188657/webrev.00/raw_files/new/test/sun/security/ssl/javax/net/ssl/SSLParameters/UseCipherSuitesOrder.java). However, it is directly working on the listening socket (`doServerSide()`). So my question is, is there a way to set `SSLParameters` for a `Server` object ? It would as well be okay to do the config via XML, but I'm  not sure if it is supported.

Comment: Only when they update Jetty.

Comment: @EJP Okay, Thanks! I was wondering if there was a way to access the server socket to set the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but from reading the source code, it looks like
it would be easy to subclass SslContextFactory to do what you need (override the
newSslServerSocket() method, and set the parameters after calling the superclass method). Then you can reference YourOwnSslContextFactory from the XML.

Comment: Thanks, didn't get a chance to try that. In the meanwhile I filed a bug with jetty.